# How to build any project statically?

Tags: linux

This could be very generic question. Particularly, I am trying to build [`gdb-8.1`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) statically. But `--enable-static`, `-fPIC`, `CFLAGS=-static`, `CXXFLAGS=-static` haven't worked for me.

I know, it is rare for anyone to be building a binary statically, but there are cases. Why don't the developers provide facility/option to build a binary statically?

Specifically, `libinproctrace.so` is not being built statically.

Comment: Which parts of gdb aren't being built statically with your configuration?

Comment: libinproctrace.so